# Using running CMD commands in C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a program that I want to send cmd msg, initially sending a msg from CMD is `msg * Hello Worlld`, I have tried it the same way in **C#** but I have failed to get it right.

```
Process WindowsProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();

private void WindowsNotifier(string msg)
{
    PSI.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    PSI.Arguments = "/c msg * '"+msg+"'";
    WindowsProcess.StartInfo = PSI;
    WindowsProcess.Start();
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can simply do this:

```
private void WindowsNotifier(string msg)
{
    Process.Start("cmd", @"/c msg * " + msg);
}
```

`/c` to close the cmd prompt or `/k` to keep it open.
I am assuming you are trying to do `msg * TEXT_HERE` in cmd prompt.

Alternatively, you can type your commands in a text file, save it as .bat batch file. Then simply run:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(batchFilePath);
```

Comment: Thank You Liren, Its working with a Windows service that just can't seem to display a message when i start the Service service

Comment: @KizitoSteven Under normal circumstances, Windows services cannot interact with the desktop, which includes the cmd prompt. There are steps to let it, but it's better to out put the messages to a log file.